# How to get rid of Optional() around printout of NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()?

Tags: ios

I stored my value using the following:

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Value1", forKey: "Key1")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Key1"))
```

The output to console is:

```
Optional(Value1)
```

How do I get rid of the "Optional()" so it just prints "Value1"?

Comment: I was using an early version of xcode6, still figuring out language changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object is optional since it may be nil.  You should unwrap it like so:

```
if let object = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Key1") {

    println(object);

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it can't then be used as an instance variable. I also get the error: variable used within its initial value